# Windows IPC analog to Linux Unix domain and Netlink sockets

Tags: linux, windows, ipc, unix-socket, netlink

On Linux a fairly common method for IPC between userland processes and services is, for example, a socket interface (either Unix domain or netlink).

Simply -- What is the Windows analog of this and how do userland processes communicate with services?

To set the stage: Assume I have a background service running that monitors devices on a network. If I wanted to write a program to utilize the services provided by this service, what would be the common "Windows-way" of doing this?

If I am completely off-base here, what is the common way a Windows service may extend itself on the Windows OS so other processes may know it is actively listening for connections?

Comment: What about UDP on windows with Winsock 2?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, I'm sure that approach would work. Is this a common design method? That is what I am looking for with this question -- the common design methodologies for this kind of communication.

Comment: Frankly, I would check first things from Boost, like [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)

Comment: Note: for communication with the kernel, the Windows way is just to add new syscalls! No need to overcomplicate things there. (Obviously, not everyone can do that)

Answer (score 4):

Windows has named pipes,

> "A named pipe is a named, one-way or duplex pipe for communication
>   between the pipe server and one or more pipe clients. All instances of
>   a named pipe share the same pipe name, but each instance has its own
>   buffers and handles, and provides a separate conduit for client/server
>   communication. The use of instances enables multiple pipe clients to
>   use the same named pipe simultaneously."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx